# How to use vue to route to different pages and display their title and text?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am making a post website in vue.
This is my problem:

There are 2 pages, one for all the blogs, and the other one where you can view the blog.
I am working with vuex.
When I click on one of the blogs, I get sent to the viewblog page and I see the title of the correct blog, so no problem with that.

What I want to do, seems simple.
I want a viewblog page with two items: **a title and text**. These two should come from the **store** (vuex).

This is the viewblog page for now:

```
<template>
  <div class="post">
      <h1>{{ $route.params.title }}</h1>
      // here I want my text from the store.
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

And this is the library:

```
<template>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <Card :post="post" v-for="(post, index) in cards" :key="index" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "../components/Card.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Card,
  },
  computed: {
    cards() {
      return this.$store.state.cards;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
// ...
</style>
```

To the library, there belongs a card:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <router-link
      :post="post"
      :to="{ name: 'Post', params: { id: post.index, title: post.title } }"
    >
      <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="title">{{ post.title }}</div>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Card",
  props: ["post"],
};
</script>
<style>
// ...
</style>
```

This is my vue-router:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: () => import('../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/post/:id',
    name: 'Post',
    component: () => import('../views/Post.vue')
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to)
  let documentTitle = `${ process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE } - ${to.name}`
  if (to.params.title) {
    documentTitle += ` - ${ to.params.title }`
  }
  document.title = documentTitle
  next()
})

export default router
```

Finally, the store (vuex):

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
    state: {
        cards: [{
                title: "Blog 1",
                text: "This is blog 1",
                index: 1,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 2",
                text: "This is blog 2",
                index: 2,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 3",
                text: "This is blog 3",
                index: 3,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 4",
                text: "This is blog 4",
                index: 4,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 5",
                text: "This is blog 5",
                index: 5,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 6",
                text: "This is blog 6",
                index: 6,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 7",
                text: "This is blog 7",
                index: 7,
            },
        ],
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
});
```

This is the result in the library:
[image: Result (library)]
And this is the result in the viewblog page when I click on blog 1:
[image: Result (view blog)]
**For Clarity**: **beneath the title, there would be text, which is coming from the store. So in this example that text would be** `This is blog 1`

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I'd suggest that you write a [vueX Getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) with a parameter to select a given Card fitting the criteria (same id)

Comment: could you please show the solution with your code based on mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Approach 1: pass by route params

You can define a [getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) function to select the given Blogtext.
Pass the `:id` of the `blog-route` as a `param`, so that you can use it as a filter in your `getter`.
Then within that getter define a simple filter logic. I did it with `forEach`, but there are other options to filter the array, pick one that fits your needs.

Within the `component` you can map the getter, and call it in a computed property with the id passed via the route, and voila, it should return the text of that specific blog post.

**VueX Store**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

export default createStore({
    state: {
        cards: [{
                title: "Blog 1",
                text: "This is blog 1",
                index: 1,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 2",
                text: "This is blog 2",
                index: 2,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 3",
                text: "This is blog 3",
                index: 3,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 4",
                text: "This is blog 4",
                index: 4,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 5",
                text: "This is blog 5",
                index: 5,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 6",
                text: "This is blog 6",
                index: 6,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 7",
                text: "This is blog 7",
                index: 7,
            },
        ],
    },
    getters: {
      blogTextById: (state) => (index) => {
         let foundText;
         state.cards.forEach((card) => { 
           // cast both indexes to Number, so that we won't run into 
           //unexpected type-mismatch. Since index might be coming 
           // from an URL, it's likely that it is stored as a splitted 
           // string, holding only a number. 
           // e.g.: index = "2" instead of index = 2 
           if (Number(card.index) === Number(index)) foundText = card.text;
         });
         return foundText;
      },
    },
});
```

**ViewBlogComponent**

```
<template>
  <div class="post">
      <h1>{{ $route.params.title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ blogText }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      blogTextGetter: 'blogTextById',
    }),
    blogText() {
      return this.blogTextGetter(this.$route.params.id);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

## Approach 2: pass id as prop, get whole card

This approach needs a few more changes, some of which alter your general approach of using the params of a route.
We would introduce a new prop to your `viewBlogPage` which only represents the `id || index` of the blog to view. Then we use that ID to fetch the whole card-item and we display all data, that we want to display.

In your `LibraryCardComponent` you overload the route call with the `title` param, which is not inherently bad practice, but it's hard to follow, without knowing about this specific behaviour. It also introduces a tight coupling between the component and the `$route` Object. But since you use it in your `beforeEach` hook I will let it stay there.

### So what do we do?

We change the route definition for `Post` to enable [Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode)

**Route Definitions**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: () => import('../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/post/:id',
    name: 'Post',
    // Here we enable the passing of props.
    // The boolean mode passes all params defined as props with the same name as the param
    // So :id will be available as prop 'id' in the Component.
    props: true,
    component: () => import('../views/Post.vue')
  }
]
```

Now we have to introduce the prop to our component for later use.

**ViewBlogPage**

```
<template>
  <div class="post">
      <h1>{{ blogPost.title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ blogPost.text }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
   
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      required: true,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      blogById: 'blogById',
    }),
    blogPost() {
      return this.blogById(this.id);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

And the getter from approach one could be written as a getBlog Getter instead of a getBlogText Getter

**VueX Getters**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

export default createStore({
    state: {
        cards: [{
                title: "Blog 1",
                text: "This is blog 1",
                index: 1,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 2",
                text: "This is blog 2",
                index: 2,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 3",
                text: "This is blog 3",
                index: 3,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 4",
                text: "This is blog 4",
                index: 4,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 5",
                text: "This is blog 5",
                index: 5,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 6",
                text: "This is blog 6",
                index: 6,
            },
            {
                title: "Blog 7",
                text: "This is blog 7",
                index: 7,
            },
        ],
    },
    getters: {
      blogById: (state) => (index) => {
         // cast both to Number() to prevent unexpected type-mismatch
         return state.cards.find(c => Number(c.index) === Number(index));
      },
    },
});
```

With this approach your `title` and `text` display is no longer tightly coupled to the route params, but reactively coupled with your state from vueX.

I hope one of the approaches fits your needs.

Comment: it does not work yet...

Comment: I do not get errors, but it just does not get displayed in the browser

Comment: I'll take a look at it, give me a moment. @EmielVandeVeire

Comment: thanks a lot, hope you will find a solution!

Comment: @EmielVandeVeire I worked this code into an existing project and it works. 
Can you please try to narrow it down which part is failing? Try calling the getter with a hardcoded index of 1 for example. And first and foremost: Try this in the getter function : `if (Number(card.index) === Number(index))`. Maybe it works as expected, but the index from either store, or the route params might not be of equal type. I can imagine, that the Param from the route is being parsed into a string at some point, since it originates from a string.

Comment: is it possible that i start a live share session on vscode, so you can show me what you mean exactly

Comment: No it's not possible. 
I updated the answer with pretty much copy&paste-ready files. It should work as expected, if it doesn't work for you, then please try to narrow it down to the actual breakpoint as much as possible.

Comment: @EmielVandeVeire Added a new variant.

Comment: I'm sorry that I kept asking for more information.... Now I tested your code properly and it did work. Thank you sooooo much for the solution.

Comment: One more question, what if I want to do this with more variables, for example not only text but also author, image...

Comment: @EmielVandeVeire That depends on where and how you store the data. But initially I'd suggest going with approach 2 for scalable usage. Since all Content from one BlogPost should be related to the BlogPosts id, you could either simply add the data to the blogPost Object, or even if you have separated sections (e.g.: image database with imagepath and blogpostid as datapoints) you can then simply add getters to those separated sections based on the already given id from the component. I hope that makes sense for you